# Can Ubuntu be used to make money?

Tags: commercial, law, software

I plan to sell course(s) on Udemy by using Ubuntu. As you predict, there will be everything what the Ubuntu has (such as screens, icons, logos, symbols, tools, softwares etc. and their use) in the course videos.

However, I want to know this is legal or not.

---

An answer is suggested but I don't think that it is enough for my question because I can't see a clear definition such as "Ubuntu is under GPL", "Ubuntu is open source", or "Ubuntu is free" on ubuntu.com. Therefore, I can't determine an answer for the question I asked.

Definitions on https://ubuntu.com/licensing is another cause to this question:

> Ubuntu is a collection of thousands of computer programs and documents created by a range of individuals, teams and companies. Each of these programs may come under a different licence.

> Ubuntu contains licensed and copyrighted works that are not application software. For example, the default Ubuntu installation includes documentation, images, sounds, video clips and firmware.

> All of the application software installed by default is free software. In addition, we install some hardware drivers that are available only in binary format, but such packages are clearly marked in the restricted component.

Comment: It would be intriguing to find out if Mint or BEP production facilities have any Ubuntu-based systems, as those would literally be used to make money :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that since you are not reselling the software you should be fine. And also, since the default installation is free, you are not doing piracy by giving for free paid content.

Also I've seen many Udemy course using Ubuntu, Windows or MacOs and since they're still on Udemy, so you shoulden't worry too much.

If you're still worried about it, consider reading the [Ubuntu licensing webpage](https://ubuntu.com/licensing)

Answer (score 2):

You should be OK. The software is, itself, free and, even if it were not, you are not selling it or giving out copies, so that, too, shouldn't be an issue.

The only thing you need to pay attention to is not to misrepresent your content as official "Ubuntu" content. The Ubuntu brand is owned by Canonical and they will come after you if you make content that could be mistaken for something Canonical may be sponsoring (which, I assume, it's not).